# Альтернативы C++ для создания DLL

Tags: c#, c++, golang, rust

Я увлекаюсь созданием модов для игр, зачастую приходится писать ASI (DLL) плагины, казалось бы C++ отлично подходит для этого, но мне он очень не нравится (мой любимый ЯП - Java), хотелось спросить, есть ли альтернативы плюсам, чтобы можно было делать DLL и использовать библиотеки, написанные на C++, например ScriptHook для GTA V или RED4ext для Cyberpunk 2077, знаю есть GoLang и Rust, но вот не могу понять, подходят ли они для моих целей или нет, ещё слышал, что в C# что-то есть, но не понимаю, могу ли я как-то использовать C++ библиотеку

Comment: C++ почти стандарт в гейминдустрии. Ещё Шарп. Поэтому, хотите писать - используйте их. Раст в принципе может в будущем занять немного эту нишу, но пока не понятно.

Comment: При желании можно писать dll на java, взаимодействуя с библиотеками на С++ через JNI. Но это прям жесткая перверсия.